# How to set and get roomName(Group Name) while creating XMPPRoom?

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, xmppframework

i am trying to create XMPPRoom where can not able to set roomname and also received stanza format doesn't contain room name, please help me out to fix this problem in backend can able to see roomName.

Here it is my code to create xmppRoom.

```
    func createGroupChat(){

   // membersToInvite = members

    let xmppRoomMemoryStorage = XMPPRoomMemoryStorage()

    let currentTimeMills = self.currentTimeMillis()
    let createdBy = (appDelegate.xmppStream?.myJID.user)! as String

    let jidString = String(format: "group%@_%@%@",currentTimeMills,createdBy,"@conference.hostname")

    let xmppJid = XMPPJID(string: jidString)
    let xmppRoom = XMPPRoom.init(roomStorage: xmppRoomMemoryStorage, jid: xmppJid)


    xmppRoom?.activate(appDelegate.xmppStream)
    xmppRoom?.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    xmppRoom?.join(usingNickname: appDelegate.xmppStream?.myJID.full(), history: nil)

}

func xmppRoomDidCreate(_ sender: XMPPRoom!) {

    print(sender)

}


 func xmppRoomDidJoin(_ sender: XMPPRoom!) {

    sender.fetchConfigurationForm()

    for JID in selectedParticipantsAry {

        sender.editPrivileges([XMPPRoom.item(withAffiliation: "member", jid: XMPPJID(string: JID as! String))])

        sender.inviteUser(XMPPJID(string: JID as! String), withMessage: "THIS IS GROUP MESSAGE")

    }

}


func xmppRoom(_ sender: XMPPRoom!, didFetchConfigurationForm configForm: DDXMLElement!)
{

    let newConfig: DDXMLElement = configForm.copy() as! DDXMLElement
    let fields = newConfig.elements(forName: "field")

    for field in fields {
        let vars = field.attribute(forName: "var")
        // Make Room Persistent
        if (vars?.stringValue == "muc#roomconfig_persistentroom") {
            field.removeChild(at: 0)
            field.addChild(DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue : "1"))

        }else if (vars?.stringValue == "muc#roomconfig_roomname"){

            field.removeChild(at: 0)
            field.addChild(DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue : "GroupNameString"))
        }
    }

    sender.configureRoom(usingOptions: newConfig)

}

  func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream!, didSend message: XMPPMessage!){

 <message to="group1480576001764.846924_XXX@conference.hostname"><x   xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user"><invite to="XXXXX@hostname">   <reason>THIS IS GROUP MESSAGE</reason></invite></x></message>  

 }

func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream!, didReceive message: XMPPMessage!){

  <message xmlns="jabber:client"  from="group148057strong text6001764.846924_XXXX@conference.hostname" to="XXXX@hostname/33932018081480575881630558" type="groupchat" id="75252205"><x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user"><status code="104"></status></x>   </message>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there are two different `Room Name`:

1. `groupxxx` in

   String(format:"group%@_%@%@",currentTimeMills,createdBy,"@conference.hostname")

in format of `roomName@conference.hostname`.

2. `GroupNameString` set in the configuration form.

Which one were you talking about?

For #1, that's in the stanza as `from`, you just need to take it out from the jid.

For #2, it won't be included in the stanza, you have to request for room info. http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#disco-roominfo

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i am talking about #2. how i can request for room info ?

Comment: @Bucket check the link I sent, you need to send a query for the room info.

Comment: Thanks, here i m requesting with query but not luck.

Comment: @Bucket can you show me your query and result? Just add to your question.